# Android NDK - Multithreading is slowing down rendering

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, android-ndk

I have an Android app with a C++ library which uses pthreads to break down rendering tasks. This is for devices running Android 4+.

Lets say I have a 100 x 100 array of elements into which I repetitively do CPU-intensive processing.  Currently I'm breaking the array up into four 25 x 100 element chunks and handing it off to four Posix threads (from a pool of stalled, pre-created threads).  This gives an almost 4x speed increase on iOS and desktop Mac but slower results than single-threading under Android.

So the same code is used successfully to speed up the app on iOS or desktop Mac but in Android it often makes it even slower.

I have done some tests on it and only quite big junks of data speed up when using multi threading. If the whole process (all threads) takes around 2 seconds or more it will speed up in multi threading mode but if it is less (say only takes about 400ms) it will be either the same speed or slower than just calling the rendering function normally. Which could point to thread switching being really slow. The bigger the processing tasks, the more they profit from multithreading. My tasks are usually not as big, but not fast enough in single threading mode.

I have also noticed that on ARM builds the speed difference between slower multi threading and the faster single threading is quite significant (almost twice as fast in multi threading rather than single threading) whereas on x86 builds the multi and single threaded versions will run at about the same speed as single threading on ARM builds. So x86 builds do not get slower on multithreading but also not faster.

Has anyone else had the same behaviour or knows where the slowdown could come from? Are there any special requirements for multithreading on Android? Unfortunately I can't really post any code at the moment but it is all standard posix threading code which works fine on iOS and Mac in general and has been in use for years.

Comment: There could be the difference in the hardware of your current Andriod and your previous iOS and Mac(number of core)...

Comment: I have tried several Android test devices and it is the same behaviour across them. Some have 2 cores, some 4. The iPad has 2. The actual speed is less important in this case than the difference between a single threaded and multi threaded version on the same device. The multi threaded version should be faster than the single threaded version (and it is on iOS and Mac) but is slower or the same speed on Android.

Comment: Multi-threaded does not necessarily imply multi-core.  If your device is rooted and supports systrace you can see exactly what's going on.  For an example, see http://bigflake.com/systrace/ .

Comment: Thanks for the link, ill check that out. Unfortunately they are not rooted. I know multi threading does not imply multi core but what I want to know is why/how multi threading is slowing down my app on my test devices which are multi core.

Comment: On android by default multithreading == multicore (if hardware is present of course). I don't have this issue and manage to get expected speedup using CPU threading on Android. Try a benchmark from the web to see if the issue is in your code or on your Android setup.

Comment: Thanks Joky, I tried a couple of benchmark apps on a few devices and the number of operations increase on multi threading but the time it takes to execute seems to be getting slower. I tried Linpack, MPAC multithreaded benchmark and AnTuTu though the last one doesn't show me the difference between single and multi threaded operations. Do you get the same result on multithreaded benchmarks?

Answer (score 2):

Android vendors aggressively optimize for battery life which includes keeping number of cores (hot-plugged) and their individual (if possible) frequency low.

Generic idea for managing number of cores online is to keep an eye on system load for a period of time (window). If load persists and is above a threshold, system will bring necessary additional available cores online. Such decision taking afaik always happens via a user-level daemon. This approach is generally very different from desktops since being able to bring cores online/offline and benefit of it is mostly SoC dependent.

Managing cpu frequency is also similar, if load persists cpu freq is increased but there is a more settled mechanism for this provided by Linux called [cpu-freq](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/index.txt) and due to that it is similar between desktop and mobile.

So it is very possible that you are creating a cpu load pattern that's not triggering core bring up or freq increase. (as you also describe within your description)